# Including OpenCV source in project without installation

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm currently trying to setup an OpenCV project using CMake.
I want to have the highest portability between machines so I thought I can achieve it by including the OpenCV source and compiling it and link it in CMake to the executable.

I'm not quite sure how to go about it because I'm a beginner to CMake and OpenCV. However, I would like to avoid installing it on the machine as much as possible as I would just want to build it and run on a machine.

So far, I've looked at the possibility of including the source of OpenCV in the CMakeFiles.txt like so:

```
add_subdirectory(opencv-3.1.0)
target_link_libraries(foo opencv-core)
```

However, it hasn't worked for me so far.
Can anyone provide me with suggestions?

Thank you.

EDIT:
The main problem I've been encountering so far is that once I use make install to move all the binaries into place, it will try to move the compiled version of OpenCV into the install location which I'm not sure how to avoid using it.

Comment: Instead of including the source checkout ExternalProject_Add: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/module/ExternalProject.html You can use this will download the source automatically and compile it with the project making it a dependency of your project.

Comment: `it hasn't worked for me so far.` - What **exact problem** you encounter while using this approach? ([edit] your question and include this information into it).